# How does Henri Durcard enter the jail?

Tags: plot-explanation, batman-begins

In *Batman Begins*, Henri Ducard (Ra's al Ghul) meets Bruce Wayne inside a jail. How did he manage to enter the jail? He isn't a jailer nor his lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's head of the League of Shadows he can do pretty much anything he wants.

It seems **very likely** that he **bribed** the guards in the Bhutanese Jail where Bruce was being kept.

Recall, he was *waiting* for Bruce in *solitary confinement* (where Bruce has *only just been sent*)....and the guards don't seem to worry about him being there...they even **open the door for him**.